# Count variable values in r

Tags: r

I am collecting data that looks like this:

```
# Data
df <- data.frame("Hospital" = c("Buge Hospital", "Buge Hospital", "Greta Hospital", "Greta Hospital",
                                "Makor Hospital", "Makor Hospital"),
                 "Period" = c("Jul-18","Aug-18", "Jul-19","Aug-19", "Jul-20","Aug-20"),
                 "Medical admissions" = c(12,56,0,40,5,56),
                 "Surgical admissions" = c(10,2,0,50,20,56),
                 "Inpatient admissions" = c(9,5,6,0,60,96))

df
```

Now I do want to get total entries per each month hence I need to calculate totals of each month variables in every year and create another column for totals.

I have tried but this is not working

```
df['totals'] = df [sum(2:5)]
```

How do I get sum totals of each row of every month in a year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `rowSums(df[3:5])`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

```r
library(data.table)
# Data
df <- data.frame("Hospital" = c("Buge Hospital", "Buge Hospital", "Greta Hospital", "Greta Hospital",
                                "Makor Hospital", "Makor Hospital"),
                 "Period" = c("Jul-18","Aug-18", "Jul-19","Aug-19", "Jul-20","Aug-20"),
                 "Medical admissions" = c(12,56,0,40,5,56),
                 "Surgical admissions" = c(10,2,0,50,20,56),
                 "Inpatient admissions" = c(9,5,6,0,60,96))

#base r
df$total <- df$Medical.admissions+df$Surgical.admissions+df$Inpatient.admissions

df
#>         Hospital Period Medical.admissions Surgical.admissions
#> 1  Buge Hospital Jul-18                 12                  10
#> 2  Buge Hospital Aug-18                 56                   2
#> 3 Greta Hospital Jul-19                  0                   0
#> 4 Greta Hospital Aug-19                 40                  50
#> 5 Makor Hospital Jul-20                  5                  20
#> 6 Makor Hospital Aug-20                 56                  56
#>   Inpatient.admissions total
#> 1                    9    31
#> 2                    5    63
#> 3                    6     6
#> 4                    0    90
#> 5                   60    85
#> 6                   96   208

#data.table
setDT(df)

df[,total:=rowSums(.SD),.SDcols = patterns("admissions$")]

df
#>          Hospital Period Medical.admissions Surgical.admissions
#> 1:  Buge Hospital Jul-18                 12                  10
#> 2:  Buge Hospital Aug-18                 56                   2
#> 3: Greta Hospital Jul-19                  0                   0
#> 4: Greta Hospital Aug-19                 40                  50
#> 5: Makor Hospital Jul-20                  5                  20
#> 6: Makor Hospital Aug-20                 56                  56
#>    Inpatient.admissions total
#> 1:                    9    31
#> 2:                    5    63
#> 3:                    6     6
#> 4:                    0    90
#> 5:                   60    85
#> 6:                   96   208
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: what if all variables don't have ```admissions``` pattern?

Comment: @LivingstoneM you also can `.SDcols = 3:5` .Using names is more robust